# Load a String to Case Object in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following objects:

```
  sealed abstract class ImputationStrategy(name: String)

  object ImputationStrategy {
    case object Mean extends ImputationStrategy("Mean")
    case object Median extends ImputationStrategy("Median")
    case object Mode extends ImputationStrategy("Mode")

    def fromString(imputeStrategy: String): Option[ImputationStrategy] = imputeStrategy.toLowerCase match {
      case "mean"   => Some(Mean)
      case "median" => Some(Median)
      case "mode"   => Some(Mode)
      case _        => None
    }

  }
```

I use this in another Config object that I load during application startup.

```
case class ImputerConfig(strategy: ImputationStrategy = ImputationStrategy.Mean)
```

But unfortunately, when I parse it like this:

```
  imputerConfig = ImputationStrategy.fromString(cfg.getString("imputer.strategy")).orElse(ImputationStrategy.Mean)
```

It says that it is expecting an Option but found ImputationStrategy.Mean.type. Is there something wrong in the way that I'm trying to parse a String to case object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getOrElse`:

```
imputerConfig = ImputationStrategy.fromString(cfg.getString("imputer.strategy")).getOrElse(ImputationStrategy.Mean)
```

`orElse` accepts an `Option`. I think in you case you want to give a default object when the parsing goes wrong. Hence `getOrElse` is more appropriate due to the fact the it returns the value of the `Option` object

Comment: Very strange, The error message that IntelliJ showed me was totally misleading.